# HTML video Doesnt play

Tags: html, video, server, mp4, offline

```
<html>
   <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="video.css">
   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="banner" class="headerContent">
      <div id="header">
        <div id="headerContent" class="headerContent">
          <video autoplay   id="awsome_video" >
               <source src="http://derrylahan.comze.com/promo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="overlay">
           <h1 id="rowdy"> ROWDY RONDY ROUSEY </h1>
           <a href="test.html" id="enter">ENTER</a>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

This code works with another mp4 video but not this one any ideas ?

Thanks in advance for any help works fine off line but not on the server im using 000webhost free hosting

when i open inspect element  on chrome and look at net work i can see things loading then this message " Failed to write into a temp file: A requested file or directory could not be found at the time an operation was processed." is displayed at the bottom of the screen

Comment: http://derrylahan.comze.com/public_html/promo.mp4 redirects to an html page. Just open the link in your browser and you will see it.

Comment: any idea how i could call my video then ?

Comment: Well your 000webhost configuration could be wrong or you haven't uploaded promo.mp4 to the right location or .. there are many other possibilities. The problem is that the url to promo.mp4 is wrong. You have to fix that.

Comment: This is a problem with your use of 000webhost not with the video tag. The fact that it works for other mp4 video resources is meaningless.

Comment: so i have to use a diffarent link to promo.mp4

Comment: You have to use the right one. The real one. Which is the righ one? Well, that depends on your configuration. If you don't know how to configure 000webhost then you should search their site for instructions/search google/maybe ask in server overflow.

Comment: if  I use "http://derrylahan.comze.com/promo.mp4" the it shows a black screen but the video it self doesn't play is that an issue with the link or the video

Answer (score 0):

When you have this video on your server. Than you can stream it probably with 
src="http://serverIP_or_domain/location_of_video.mp4". But you need to make sure that the permissions of your .mp4 file are correct. (use chmod).

Comment: why does src="promo.mp4" not work even thought the video and index.html are in the same directiry

Comment: What should the permissions be ?

Comment: Because you show it on your page I would try "chmod a+rx" so every one can read and execute the program (the .mp4 file) but cannot write to it (so they are not allowed to make changes to it).

Comment: any idea what the value of that is ?

Comment: Instead of entering a value you can use this command in the command line (chmod a+rx <name of the file>). else it will probably be "chmod 755 <name of the file>" which means that you have permissions to read,write, execute and the group and all other people can only read and execute. make sure that you are in the directory where the file is in. Otherwise it will not find the file.